# Problem with selecting json object in Pyspark, which may sometime have Null values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, aws-glue

I have this big nested json object from which I need to make a Dataframe. One of the inner json elements sometimes come as empty and sometimes it comes with some values in it.

I am giving a simple example here:

When it is filled:

```
{"student_address": {"Door Number":"1234",
                     "Place":"xxxx",
                     "Zip code":"12345"}}
```

When it is empty:

```
{"student_address":""}
```

So, in the final DataFrame I have all the three columns `Door Number, Place and Zip code.` When the address is empty, I should put `Null` values in the respective columns and should fill them when there is data.

The code I tried:

```
test = test.withColumn("place",when(col("student_address") == "", lit(None)).otherwise(col("student_address.place")))\
           .withColumn("door_num",when(col("student_address") == "",lit(None)).otherwise(col("student_address.door_num")))\
           .withColumn("zip_code",when(col("student_address") == "", lit(None)).otherwise(col("student_address.zip_code")))
```

So, I am trying to check wether the value is empty or not.

This is the error I am getting:

```
AnalysisException: Can't extract value from student_address#34: need struct type but got string
```

I am not able to understand why PySpark is checking the statement in `otherwise`, when condition is met in `when` itself. (I tried giving simple values in `otherwise` instead of json path and it worked).

I am struggling to understand what is happening here and would like to know if there is any simple way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
val addressSchema = StructType(StructField("Place", StringType, false) :: Nil) # Add more fields
val schema = StructType(StructField("address", addressSchema, true) :: Nil) # the point is address is nullable
val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json("example.json")
```

Answer (score 0):

use Get JSON object with the first object with is Student_address and the column should be the name of the column.

```
df.withColumn("place",when(df.student_address== "", lit(None)).otherwise(get_json_object(col("student_address"),"$.student_address.place")))
```